# Calculating a complex arithmetic expression from Matlab in Java

Tags: java, matlab, floating-point, double, precision

I'm using Matlab to derive some symbolic equations (with variables). These are pretty tough ones which include log, tanh, atanh functions:

```
import static java.lang.Math.log;
import static java.lang.Math.tanh;

public class MathTest {

    private static double coeff(double accel_Vmax, double accel_amin, double accel_amax, double accel_x0, double accel_v0) {
        double accel_Vmax2 = Math.pow(accel_Vmax, 2);
        return -(1.6658627956859751925e-24*(618147116152812568000.0*accel_Vmax2*log(1.0 - 1.0*tanh((0.071428571428571428571*(660.0*accel_amax - 165.0*accel_amin + 14.0*accel_Vmax*atanh((4.0*accel_v0*accel_amin - 8.0*accel_v0*accel_amax - 3.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amin + 4.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amax)/(accel_Vmax*accel_amin - 4.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amax))))/accel_Vmax)) + 3.3331462164783108864e21*accel_Vmax2*log(1.0 - 1.0*tanh((0.14285714285714285714*(180.0*accel_amax - 45.0*accel_amin + 7.0*accel_Vmax*atanh((4.0*accel_v0*accel_amin - 8.0*accel_v0*accel_amax - 3.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amin + 4.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amax)/(accel_Vmax*accel_amin - 4.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amax))))/accel_Vmax)) - 6.0723863811437384517e21*accel_Vmax2*log(1.0 - 1.0*tanh((0.071428571428571428571*(180.0*accel_amax - 45.0*accel_amin + 14.0*accel_Vmax*atanh((4.0*accel_v0*accel_amin - 8.0*accel_v0*accel_amax - 3.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amin + 4.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amax)/(accel_Vmax*accel_amin - 4.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amax))))/accel_Vmax)) - 3.9876549298255135726e21*accel_Vmax2*log(1.0 - 1.0*tanh((0.14285714285714285714*(360.0*accel_amax - 90.0*accel_amin + 7.0*accel_Vmax*atanh((4.0*accel_v0*accel_amin - 8.0*accel_v0*accel_amax - 3.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amin + 4.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amax)/(accel_Vmax*accel_amin - 4.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amax))))/accel_Vmax)) - 1.8180797558373403944e21*accel_Vmax2*log(1.0 - 1.0*tanh((0.5*(60.0*accel_amax - 15.0*accel_amin + 2.0*accel_Vmax*atanh((4.0*accel_v0*accel_amin - 8.0*accel_v0*accel_amax - 3.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amin + 4.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amax)/(accel_Vmax*accel_amin - 4.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amax))))/accel_Vmax)) - 6.002895332014512297e23*accel_x0*accel_amin + 1.2005790664029024594e24*accel_x0*accel_amax + 262429425.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amin + 2.4362268723458870243e21*accel_Vmax2*log(1.0 - 1.0*tanh((0.071428571428571428571*(780.0*accel_amax - 195.0*accel_amin + 14.0*accel_Vmax*atanh((4.0*accel_v0*accel_amin - 8.0*accel_v0*accel_amax - 3.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amin + 4.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amax)/(accel_Vmax*accel_amin - 4.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amax))))/accel_Vmax)) + 8.8358676058937131753e21*accel_Vmax2*log(1.0 - 1.0*tanh((0.14285714285714285714*(60.0*accel_amax - 15.0*accel_amin + 7.0*accel_Vmax*atanh((4.0*accel_v0*accel_amin - 8.0*accel_v0*accel_amax - 3.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amin + 4.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amax)/(accel_Vmax*accel_amin - 4.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amax))))/accel_Vmax)) - 4.2543066242278358162e21*accel_Vmax2*log(1.0 - 1.0*tanh((0.071428571428571428571*(60.0*accel_amax - 15.0*accel_amin + 14.0*accel_Vmax*atanh((4.0*accel_v0*accel_amin - 8.0*accel_v0*accel_amax - 3.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amin + 4.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amax)/(accel_Vmax*accel_amin - 4.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amax))))/accel_Vmax)) - 3.1634587719706994218e21*accel_Vmax2*log(1.0 - 1.0*tanh((0.14285714285714285714*(120.0*accel_amax - 30.0*accel_amin + 7.0*accel_Vmax*atanh((4.0*accel_v0*accel_amin - 8.0*accel_v0*accel_amax - 3.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amin + 4.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amax)/(accel_Vmax*accel_amin - 4.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amax))))/accel_Vmax)) - 3.6361595097781225383e21*accel_Vmax2*log(1.0 - 1.0*tanh((0.14285714285714285714*(240.0*accel_amax - 60.0*accel_amin + 7.0*accel_Vmax*atanh((4.0*accel_v0*accel_amin - 8.0*accel_v0*accel_amax - 3.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amin + 4.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amax)/(accel_Vmax*accel_amin - 4.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amax))))/accel_Vmax)) - 472700736468785811844.0*accel_Vmax2*log(1.0 - 1.0*tanh((60.0*accel_amax - 15.0*accel_amin + accel_Vmax*atanh((4.0*accel_v0*accel_amin - 8.0*accel_v0*accel_amax - 3.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amin + 4.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amax)/(accel_Vmax*accel_amin - 4.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amax)))/accel_Vmax)) + 735312255896455259166.0*accel_Vmax2*log(-(4.0*(accel_v0*accel_amin - 2.0*accel_v0*accel_amax - 1.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amin + 2.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amax))/(accel_Vmax*accel_amin - 4.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amax)) + 101004431699873120300.0*accel_Vmax2*log(1.0 - 1.0*tanh((0.071428571428571428571*(540.0*accel_amax - 135.0*accel_amin + 14.0*accel_Vmax*atanh((4.0*accel_v0*accel_amin - 8.0*accel_v0*accel_amax - 3.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amin + 4.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amax)/(accel_Vmax*accel_amin - 4.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amax))))/accel_Vmax)) + 3.5270747250077918894e21*accel_Vmax2*log(1.0 - 1.0*tanh((0.14285714285714285714*(300.0*accel_amax - 75.0*accel_amin + 7.0*accel_Vmax*atanh((4.0*accel_v0*accel_amin - 8.0*accel_v0*accel_amax - 3.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amin + 4.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amax)/(accel_Vmax*accel_amin - 4.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amax))))/accel_Vmax)) + 3.817967485777192084e21*accel_Vmax2*log(1.0 - 1.0*tanh((0.071428571428571428571*(300.0*accel_amax - 75.0*accel_amin + 14.0*accel_Vmax*atanh((4.0*accel_v0*accel_amin - 8.0*accel_v0*accel_amax - 3.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amin + 4.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amax)/(accel_Vmax*accel_amin - 4.0*accel_Vmax*accel_amax))))/accel_Vmax))))/(accel_amin - 2.0*accel_amax);
    }

    private static double atanh(double x) {
        return 0.5 * log((1.0 + x) / (1.0 - x));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("" + coeff(40, 2, 15, 0,0));
    }
}
```

As you can see, the expression in coeff() function is pretty awful. There is a repeating pattern in which double-precision variable-point arithmetics fail:

```
log(1.0 - 1.0*tanh(...))
```

Usually result of tanh(...) is like 0.9998232, 0.9892348, 0.99999999843, 0.999999999999... But always at some time it outputs 1 and log() goes NaN.

I wonder if there is a solution to calculate this expression without calling Matlab API from Java. I'm aiming at performance and can't afford to use Matlab in production. Is it achievable or out of scope?

Comment: If it is a repeating pattern you can replace it with recursion?

Comment: By repeating pattern I mean this function is called in similar way few times, with different arguments. I don't think I'm able to manipulate this expression, because it's way too hard. I might say it's abstract for me. It was derived from simple differential equations.

Comment: As i understand, the problem is that the result of `tanh(...)` == 1.0 sometimes, then log(0) = NaN. You can calc   tanh(...) separately, and if it is == 1, you can replace it with 0.99999999999 or handle it other way you want.

Comment: I tried in other way, if log(0) then return eg. 1000. This results in wrong computation. Whole precision of result relies on a resolution of this close-to-one number and taking a logarithm of it. If you take a look at eg. log function, you can see how fast the result change when you reach 0 argument.

Comment: Have you tried simulating your differential equations? If so, did they behave chaotically for the sorts of numbers that are giving you trouble?

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the expression `1-tanh(x)` to `2/(e^2x - 1)`. That should take care of the catastrophic cancellation going on inside the logarithm. (You'll still need to worry about a zero denominator at x near 0, but simply special-casing should be sufficient.)

EDIT: Going further, you can leverage `Math.log1p()`, which is tailor-made for this sort of thing:

```
  log(1 - tanh(x))
= log(1 - (e^2x - 1)/(e^2x + 1))
= log(2/(e^2x + 1))
= log(2) - log(e^2x + 1)
= log(2) - log1p(e^2x)
```

It looks like your equation is a little more complicated than just `log(1-tanh(x))`, but the basic recipe is, simplify as much as possible, then leverage math functions such as `Math.log1p()` to avoid regions of instability. (In general, the only number you want your numbers to be "close to" is zero.)

Comment: I replaced all occurrences of 'log(1 - tanh(x))' with 'log(2) - log1p(e^2x)' and it calculated. However I need to find a solution to execute this automatically..

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for there... a way to automatically, symbolically derive numerically stable formulae? I don't know of one, either in Java or in Matlab.

Comment: I simply want to replace all occurrences of `log(1 - tanh(x))` with `log(2) - log1p(exp(2*x))`, where `x` is an expression.